# Taxonomy terms as numbers?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

Creating real estate website, i have a lot of exposed filters.
For year when the object is built i have number field which in views is as exposed filter.
When user makes input he puts year 1961 for example.

User searching in exposed filter writes 1961 and filter is set up like "equal or higher" so he gets all objects made 1961 and higher. Works fine.

But i have a problem with floors.
For floors i have vocabulary:
ground floor
1
2
3
4
etc..
attic

I cant use number field because of ground floor and attic so i had to use taxonomy.
But now i cant use equal or higer as exposed filter so if user picks number 3 he only gets appartments with 3 floors.

Answer (score 3):

You could still use floors as numeric field, having numbers as keys and display output as needed.

Example of "List (integer)" values:

> ```
> -1|Basement
> 0|Ground floor
> 1|1
> 2|2
> 3|3
> 100|Attic
> ```

This would allow you the same logic for floors.

**EDIT:**
When selecting the field as a filter in Views you need to choose the `delta` value. It looks something like `Content: Floors (field_floors:delta)`. This will give you the integer filter options such as `Is greater than or equal to`.

Comment: This works but how can i achive "equal or higer" in views exposed filter with it ? I tried using slider but it works only with integer (ubfortunately not workung with List(integer)

Comment: For all integer fields you should be able to select `Is greater than or equal` in the field settings under `Filter criteria` in Views.

Comment: I only have: " Is one of, Is all of, Is none of, Is empty (NULL),  Is not empty (NOT NULL). (using "List (integer)" as field).

Comment: @BigBrother2010 When selecting field you have to choose the delta value.

Comment: Cheers for helping out enzipher, but for some reason delta value is not visible for this field.

Comment: @BigBrother2010 I tried this out with Drupal 7.14 and Views 3.5 and it works for me. I really can't tell why you don't have a delta value for the field. I can only suggest that you double check your field and Views settings to make sure all is correct.

Comment: I am using D7.19 - Views 3.5. I created new view for this content type and delta fields are showing up only for term reference field, image field and text field. For integer, list (integer) and decimal field it does not. I have tried same on another installation and got same result (D7.16 - Views 3.5).